# Visual Studio prebuild event for deleting certain file with naming convention

Tags: visual-studio

I am using prebuild event commands to delete certain folders in my wwwroot directory.

Now, I need to do that for certain dll's in the bin folder that follow a certain naming convention like,

```
Foundation.*.dll
```

Currently, I am using the following to delete a directory:

```
rd /s /q "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\siteroot.local\App_Config\Include\zzz.Project"
```

I need a variation on this to delete just certain dlls.

Comment: This is more a question about the Windows command shell. not about C# and Visual Studio. The [del](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/del) command accepts wildcards so ths would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
del /s /q "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc.vitas-p.local\bin\Project.*.*"
```

This wound up being the answer.